# How to set your input fields with local storage variables using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am making a mobile web app using jquery mobile and jquery.
Now I have it so far that when I check my checkbox it saves my variables into the local storage from your browser. But it won't put these variables back into my input fields.

Here is my script. The function validate() saves the variables into local storage.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        if (localStorage["mail"]) {
            $('#mail').val(localStorage["mail"]);
        }else{
            $('#mail').val("");
        }
        if (localStorage["password"]) {
            $('#password').val(localStorage["password"]);
        }else{
            $('#password').val("");
        }
});
function validate(){
    if ($("remember:checked")) {
         var mail= $("#mail").val();
         var password= $("#password").val();

         localStorage["mail"] = mail ;
         localStorage["password"] = password;
         localStorage.setItem("mail", mail) ;
         localStorage.setItem("password", password) ;

     }else{
       alert("You didn't check it! Let me check it for you.")
     }
}
```

Can anybody help me ?

thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong for setting and getting an item in local storage Use

```
localStorage.setItem('someval',1)
localStorage.getItem('someval'); // 1
```

Comment: Local storage stores data as string...make sure you ParseInt(your data) before you make any arithmetic operation

Comment: OP's way also works. `setItem` and `getItem` are not the only way.

Comment: Oops my wrong in ur jquery script change
if($("#remember")is(":checked") {

Answer (score 0):

it seems that `$("remember:checked")` is not a valid selector (a `.` or a `#` is missing). So probably your values are never saved into localstorage

when you check for existence of an element you should use `length` property instead

```
if ($("<your selector>").length) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Yes they are, I can see them in firebug ;)

Comment: it can work only if you have an element `<remember></remember>`

Comment: Go for if ($("#remember")is(":checked") { make sure you set its id to remember

Comment: Guys, the problem is not storing the values, the problem is getting the values back from my local storage

Comment: try localStorage.getItem('someval');